# Isometries of two dimensional space

Tags: geometry

I know that isometries of R^n are composed of orthogonal transformations followed by translation. My questions are:

1. In 2-D space, there are glide reflections, but why must the glide be according to the axis of reflection? Why can't we reflect according to some axis and then translate according to another vector altogether?
2. Why are there no glide rotations in 2-D space?

Answer (score 1):

1. The composition of a reflection in a line $l_1$ and translation along a line $l_2$ equals the composition of a reflection in some other line $l_3$ and translation along $l_3$.
2. The composition of a rotation and a translation equals a rotation around some other point.